# SQL code to pad leading zeros and get last 3 months varchar

Tags: sql

I need SQL code to pad leading zeros and get last 3 months as varchar. Sample code below. My syntax is not right.

```
select RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), datepart(mm, dateadd(mm, -3, getdate())), 2)
```

result I am after:   02

Comment: What error, or undesirable result, do you get? Be specific - maybe you don't understand the terms, but others reading can help explain it.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your question.

Comment: sql server, you need one more closing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, I think you are missing a closing paren:

```
select RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4),
                            datepart(month, dateadd(month, -3, getdate()
                                                   )
                                    )
                            ), 2
            )
```